# How to remove head category but keep subcategory in url magento

Tags: url, url-rewrite, category-products

Currently my url structure is as following:

**parameters**: example.com/head-category/sub-category/product-name

**actual url**: example.com/gear/balls/superball-0192

I would like to change this to:

**parameters**: example.com/sub-category/product-name

**actual url**: example.com/balls/superball-0192

But only for the URL structure. The structure in the menu, head category = main item followed by sub-categories as a subitem.

Comment: In magento 2 or magento1

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of url rewrite in magento 1 and 2 both . In magento 2

On the Admin Panel, go to `Marketing > SEO & Search> URL Rewrites`

Add url rewrite where you can give the request path and the target path.
Clear cache and run indexing then check the path.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I needed. I did not need a URL redirect. I actually want to remove the headcategory parameter from the URL. If I make a redirect, this does not change the URL structure.